# How to I find relations with the exact same set of has_many relationships using ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, rails-activerecord

I have the following Active Record Models:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :features
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :houses
end
```

How can I write a query that returns all houses that have the exact same set of many-to-many relations? So If a house has features 1,2,3, I would like exactly them while excluding:

houses that only have a subset of the features (example, 1 & 2) houses that have that set but include others (so if they have features 1,2,3 & 4 they should be excluded as well).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting with a given `House` or given set of `Features` then:

The following should work

Find the `House`s that meet the following criteria:

- the `House`s are not in the list of houses that have features other than the features provided
- the `House`s total count of features is equal to the number of features provided

```
features = [1,2,3]
House.where(
  id: House.select(:id)
           .joins(:features)
           .where.not(
             id: House.select(:id)
                      .joins(:features)
                      .where.not(features: {id: features})
           )
           .group(:id)
           .having(Feature.arel_attribute(:id).count.eq(features.size))
)
```

SQL akin to: (assuming your join table is named houses_features)

```
SELECT 
  houses.*
FROM
  houses
WHERE 
  houses.id IN ( 
     SELECT 
       houses.id 
     FROM 
       houses
       INNER JOIN houses_features ON houses.id = houses_features.house_id
       INNER JOIN features ON features.id = houses_features.feature_id
     WHERE 
       houses.id NOT IN (
         SELECT 
           houses.id 
         FROM 
           houses 
           INNER JOIN houses_features ON houses.id = houses_features.house_id
           INNER JOIN features ON features.id = houses_features.feature_id 
         WHERE 
           features.id NOT IN (1,2,3)
      )
    GROUP BY 
      houses.id
    HAVING
     COUNT(features.id) = 3
  )
```